# antlr 4 iso-8859-15 encoded file matching string containing \u0161 š

Tags: encoding, antlr, antlr4, iso-8859-15

I have this grammar:

```
KEY
: [a-zA-Z\u0160\u0161\u00C0-\u00FF][a-zA-Z_0-9\-\''\u0160\u0161\u00C0-\u00FF]* 
;
```

Reading a ISO-8859-15 encoded text file

```
new ANTLRFileStream(fileName, "ISO-8859-15")
```

with the string `Milešovka`. Why is `š` giving a token recognition error?

Trace:

```
 line 110:6 token recognition error at: ''exit    field, LT(1)={
```

EDIT: I am using antlr 4.5.1 (and have tested 4.4 - same issue).

Comment: Does ANTLRFileStream always provide a stream of *Unicode* characters to the lexer? [Then \u0161 would be right]  Or is that encoding just a way to tell it to read 8 bit bytes, without interpreting them? [Then \u00a8 would be the correct code for "š".]

Comment: I tested with \u00a8 instead of \u0161. Same error.

Comment: Correcting my self: Using \u00a8 does work.Ira Baxter your seems to be correct. Encoding just way to tell it to read 8 bit bytes.

Comment: The ANTLRFileStream scheme seems singularly silly.  If ANTLR is going to handle "16 bit" codes, why would it not always run using the Unicode character set?  What this means is that your lexer depends on the encoding of your file, which will change based on locale and even the direction of the wind.  [I guessed what your problem was based on similar silliness we had 15 years ago with our parsing tools, that made us go solve the encoding problem right].

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in a way you use to generate parser. I'm not sure what exactly could go wrong, but I managed to do a working example with your symbol, that uses maven to generate grammar.

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <listener>false</listener>
                <visitor>true</visitor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>antlr4</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

LexerGrammar.g

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

LBR: '[';
RBR: ']';
KEY
: [a-zA-Z\u0160\u0161\u00C0-\u00FF][a-zA-Z_0-9\-\''\u0160\u0161\u00C0-\u00FF]*
;
```

ParserGrammar.g

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

rul   : block+ ;
block  : LBR KEY RBR ;
```

Full example code is [here](http://github.com/Fantast/stackoverflow-test5)

Comment: Also make sure that your file is actually in `ISO-8859-15`, some editors might automatically save in "UTF-8". To test this try to actually use `UTF-8` to read file.

Comment: It is ansi encoded (ISO-8859-15) in notepad++
Milešovka
If i set it to UTF-8
Mileۯvka 

EDIT: š is x9A

Comment: So with the maven build, what does your grammar,  .g4 file  look like?

Comment: Correcting my previous comment: 
If set to ISO-8859-15 in notepad++: Milešovka
If i set it to UTF-8: Mileۯvka (i.e. x00a8)
correcting my previous comment.... as I tested with ANSI encoded as well

Answer (score 0):

Ira Baxter's comment answers the question:

> Does ANTLRFileStream always provide a stream of Unicode characters to the lexer? [Then \u0161 would be right] Or is that encoding just a way to tell it to read 8 bit bytes, without interpreting them? [Then \u00a8 would be the correct code for "š".]